# how to restore data after running rm?

Tags: data-recovery, rm

I accidently ran `sudo rm *`

I thought I was in an unimportant subfolder.

The result is that I deleted some very important files.
Is there any way to get my data back?

Comment: Witch type of file system is on partition?

Comment: @2707974 `ext4`

Comment: use this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

But I prefer `foremost`

Install foremost

```
sudo apt-get install foremost
```

Take a look at

```
man foremost
```

to learn how to use foremost.

First make an empty writable directory to save recover files in a partition other than that you are going to recover.

Then run foremost.

I am going to recover my home partition ( let's say `/dev/sda5`).

```
$ sudo foremost -t jpg -i /dev/sda5 -o /recovery/data
```

Finally set user permission to /recovery/data/ to view image. type

```
$ sudo chown YOUR_USER_NAME /recovery/data -R
```

Some important foremost command line arguments.

```
-i  :- partition/image to recover
-o :- location to store recovered files.
-t  :- built in file filter options.  you can give multiple filters by separating using commas. (e.g: for jpg and pdf: -t jpg,pdf ) 
-q :- quick mode.
```

Comment: Can it recover bash scripts?

Comment: Probably yes. Run command without type of files `-t`.

Answer (score 1):

After the steps from @2707974 above, then you can use this bash utility lines to browse millions of files quickly and painless, something like this:

```
`$ mkdir /recovery/filtered && cd /recovery/data && SKIP=1300 #SKIP value depends on your needs
$ for((j=$SKIP; j<10000; j=j+100)); do
   for i in $(ls -S . | head -n $j | tail -n 100); do
     cp $i ../filtered/;
   done;
   sleep 10;
   rm ../filtered/*;
done`
```

And then now, you can open /recovery/filtered on your file browser, and watch your history...